# iOS - Listen for network connection changes with app in background

Tags: ios, xamarin, connection, location, wifi

I'm thinking there likely is not a way to do this with how Apple likes to restrict their developers, but I would like to listen for network connection changes (wifi connections/disconnections) even while the application is in the background or closed.

My application (for iOS and Android) allows users to use a Geofence to track their location so that certain events trigger when they leave or enter their home. I'm able to do this in iOS with `CLLocationManager` and `CLCircularRegion`. That's all fine and dandy, but I would like to give the users an additional option that tracks their wifi connection to determine when to trigger leaving and entering events. That way paranoid users (like me) can trigger events when they enter and exit their home without requiring location services.

What I would like to do is have the application trigger an event when their device connects or disconnects from a wireless network. When the event occurs, I want to get information from that network such as the MAC of the wireless access point so that I can reliably determine if they are connecting to their home network or not so that I can determine if they are home based on what they set as their home wifi.

I'm fairly certain you can do this on Android, but iOS I'm not so sure. Everything related I have found requires the application to be actively running. The event would have to trigger whenever a wifi connection change happened even while the application was closed or in the background. This application is written with Xamarin (C#), but Objective-C code is acceptable.

Is there a way to do this with iOS?

Answer (score 3):

I was really bothered by the fact that listening for WiFi connect/disconnect events can be done on Android, but not iOS. So I sent a developer support request to Apple. This was a portion of their response:

> There is no supported way to detect WiFi events in the background.

They went on to tell me that using region monitoring is the way to go, blah blah blah. Not an acceptable solution since the whole idea is to eliminate the need for location services to be enabled, but oh well.

So there you have it from Apple themselves. You can't currently do this with iOS.

Answer (score 1):

No, triggering and listening to when the connection changes is unfortunately currently not supported by Apple.

As seen in [their official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) in `Table 3-1`, you can see what is permitted to have running as a `long-running background task`, which is what you want in your case.

Comment: I don't find any information you describe here at the linked page. Can you please check your link and adjust it to the documentation you've noticed in your comment?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe [this medium-post](https://medium.com/@sauvik_dolui/network-status-monitoring-on-ios-part-1-9a22276933dc) might help: Sauvik Dolui described how to generate a swift-based Network-Connection listener.

Comment: Why down-vote here? A comment, if it's not work will be fine. What's wrong with the information, how to implement an own WiFi-Connection Event-Listener?